# How to get CustomProperties displayed in RoomInfo | Unity + PUN2

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I am setting a CustomRoomProperties when a new game is started. Here:

```
public void startGame()
    {
      RoomOptions options = new RoomOptions();
      options.CleanupCacheOnLeave = true;
      options.MaxPlayers = 8; 
      options.IsOpen = true;
      options.IsVisible = true;
      Hashtable RoomCustomProps = new Hashtable();
      RoomCustomProps.Add("availablePods", gameLenghtsIs);
      options.CustomRoomProperties = RoomCustomProps;
      PhotonNetwork.JoinOrCreateRoom(createInput.text, options, TypedLobby.Default);
    }
```

And this is the RoomInfo displayed in the Lobby once a game is created:

```
public void SetRoomInfo(RoomInfo roomInfo)
    {
      RoomInfo = roomInfo;
      maxPlayetTxt.text = roomInfo.MaxPlayers + ",";
      nameRoomText.text = roomInfo.Name + ",";
      payerNumberText.text = roomInfo.PlayerCount+ "/8";
    }
```

To this RoomInfo i would want to add the created Custom Property but not really sure how. I tried:

```
    podsTxt.text = roomInfo.CustomProperties["availablePods"] + ",";
```

This resulted in nothingness.

And i tried this:

```
    podsTxt.text = roomInfo.CustomProperties["availablePods"].GetHashCode() + ",";
```

Resulted in a error.

Tried a few other things but can't get it to work.
P.S. I am using the Hashtable and the hastable does what it's sopposto to do. I would just want this value that i set at startGame()

```
   "availablePods"
```

to bi displayed when getting the room list in the lobby.

Anyone can help?

Comment: The first way you tried is correct.  Is there a problem with podsTxt being off screen, too small, or hidden in some way?  Did you try using the debugger to see if there are any keys in the custom properties at the time you try assigning to podsTxt?

Comment: It gets back as empty this way, never gets the information from the room. 
See picture: https://ibb.co/yRXSxt4
And this: https://ibb.co/2FFYVbm  .When in the room itself i can retrieve this information with 0 problems, but when in the lobby i get nothing back this way

Comment: I believe you are confused by the room properties and the lobby properties.  From docs for RoomInfo.CustomProperties: `Read-only "cache" of custom properties of a room. Set via Room.SetCustomProperties (not available for RoomInfo class!).`

Comment: You may be able to set the `CustomRoomPropertiesForLobby` to the properties you want displayed in the lobby, but be aware: `Unless a custom property is essential for matchmaking or user info, it should not be sent to the lobby, which causes traffic and delays for clients in the lobby.`

Comment: Thanks, hijinxbassist. This information helped me solve the issue. Had to work out the code for it but this information was key.

Answer (score 0):

If this help anybody, this is what wroked for me:

```
public void startGame()
{
  RoomOptions options = new RoomOptions();
  options.CleanupCacheOnLeave = true;
  options.MaxPlayers = 8; 
  options.IsOpen = true;
  options.IsVisible = true;
  Hashtable RoomCustomProps = new Hashtable();
  RoomCustomProps.Add("availablePods", gameLenghtsIs);
  options.CustomRoomProperties = RoomCustomProps;
  options.CustomRoomProperties.Add("availablePods", allPods);
  options.CustomRoomPropertiesForLobby = new string[1] { "availablePods" };
  PhotonNetwork.JoinOrCreateRoom(createInput.text, options, TypedLobby.Default);
}
```

Room Info:

```
public void SetRoomInfo(RoomInfo roomInfo)
{
  RoomInfo = roomInfo;
  maxPlayetTxt.text = roomInfo.MaxPlayers + ",";
  nameRoomText.text = roomInfo.Name + ",";
  payerNumberText.text = roomInfo.PlayerCount+ "/8";
  podsTxt.text = roomInfo.CustomProperties["availablePods"].ToString();
}
```

Thanks to hijinxbassist, i got this working.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is still confused with this, follow the below steps:

1. Create a Hashtable (Not from **System.Collections** namespace, but from **ExitGames.Client.Photon.Hashtable** namespace).
2. Add whatever Key Values pairs you want to add to the hashtable.
3. Assign this Hashtable to the **RoomOptions.CustomRoomProperties** field.
4. Create a String Array.
5. Add the Key's of the above created hashtable, whichever you want to be visible in RoomInfo.
6. Now assign this string arrat to **RoomOptions.CustomRoomPropertiesForLobby** field.
7. Now you should be able to fetch the value using **RoomInfo.CustomProperties["Key"]**.
8. Note that, Step-7 returns a Object, so make sure to cast it to desired Data Type. (int/string/float/bool..etc).

```
public void CreateRoom()
{ 
    ExitGames.Client.Photon.Hashtable customProperties = new ExitGames.Client.Photon.Hashtable();
    
    customProperties["Key_I_Want_To_Share"] = "Value1";
    customProperties["Key_I_Will_Not_Share"] = "Value2";
    
    string[] customPropertiesForLobby = new String[1]
    {
        "Key_I_Want_To_Share"
    };  

    RoomOptions roomOptions = new RoomOptions();
    roomOptions.CustomRoomProperties = customProperties;
    roomOptions.CustomRoomPropertiesForLobby = customPropertiesForLobby;
    // Add any other room options 
    
    PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom("New Room", roomOptions);
}
```

And for RoomInfo Class:

```
public void SetRoomInfo(RoomInfo roomInfo)
{
    // Fetch the value and cast it to required DataType
    string valueFromRoom = roomInfo.CustomProperties["Key_I_Want_To_Share"].ToString();
    Debug.Log("Fetched Value from Room: " + valueFromRoom);
}
```

**Note:** If you don't pass the **CustomProperties()** keys as strings in **CustomPropertiesForLobby()** then RoomInfo class cannot fetch it.